# SQL set profiling

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm setting up an automatic database backup for a website. When I try to do a backup it comes up with the error"

```
MySQL error: The 'SHOW PROFILE' feature is disabled; you need MySQL built with 'enable-profiling' to have it working
Could not save backup of database information_schema in 'export/'
File successfully saved as unversed_MC_bans.1348661703.sql.zip
File successfully saved as unversed_MG_ranks.1348661703.sql.zip
File successfully saved as unversed_TYE_TEST.1348661704.sql.zip
File successfully saved as unversed_ads.1348661704.sql.zip
```

After having a look around I find this;

```
#1289 - The 'SHOW PROFILE' feature is disabled; you need MySQL built with 'enable-profiling' to have it working
```

I exported the dump file, this was the code

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.4.7.1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Sep 26, 2012 at 05:19 AM
-- Server version: 5.1.62
-- PHP Version: 5.3.14-pl0-gentoo

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `information_schema`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `PROFILING`
--

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `PROFILING` (
  `QUERY_ID` int(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `SEQ` int(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `STATE` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `DURATION` decimal(9,6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000000',
  `CPU_USER` decimal(9,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CPU_SYSTEM` decimal(9,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CONTEXT_VOLUNTARY` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CONTEXT_INVOLUNTARY` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BLOCK_OPS_IN` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BLOCK_OPS_OUT` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MESSAGES_SENT` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MESSAGES_RECEIVED` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PAGE_FAULTS_MAJOR` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PAGE_FAULTS_MINOR` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SWAPS` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SOURCE_FUNCTION` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SOURCE_FILE` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SOURCE_LINE` int(20) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
-- in use (#1289 - The 'SHOW PROFILE' feature is disabled; you need MySQL built with 'enable-profiling' to have it working)

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

And this is the original query I am trying to run

```
mysql> SET profiling = 1; 

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql> SET profiling = 1' at line 1
```

Any inclinations of why this is happening would be fantastic... Thanks.

Comment: As it is clearly mentioned in the error message that profiling feature is not disabled and to enable it you need to build it again with that particular feature enabled. Merely creating temporary table by the name of "PROFILING" will not solve the purpose

Comment: It was automatically created. I'm not 100% sure on what to do.

Comment: Don't backup `information_schema`

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options:

- Rebuild MySQL with USE=profiling
- Upgrade phpMyAdmin
- Use a more purpose-built tool for the backup: Percona's `xtrabackup`, `mylvmbackup`, `mysqldump` or anything else, in a cronjob.